# Error in begin transaction

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I tried to do begin transaction on SQL Server, but it returns an error that I can't figure out what the real problem is. So here is some of my code I tried.

This is the error:

[image]

Code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID = xxxx; Password=xxx;");

DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
dt = dt.AddDays(60); 

string selectQuery = "BEGIN TRANSACTION UPDATE tester SET 
test_ad=@dateTimePicker1, test_ud=@dt, test_pd=@dt WHERE 
test_name=@textBox1;INSERT INTO records(testr_status, testr_name, testr_ad, 
testr_ud, testr_pd, apte_name)VALUES(@testr_status, testr_name = @comboBox1, 
testr_ad = @dateTimePicker1, testr_ud = @dt, testr_pd = @dt COMMIT";

connection.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTimePicker1",this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBox1", this.textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comboBox1",this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testr_status",SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);

int iResult = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (iResult > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved ", "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
else
    MessageBox.Show("Record not saved ", "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Dispose();
command.Dispose();
```

Comment: `testr_name = @comboBox1` makes sense in an `UPDATE`. It **does not** makes sense in an `INSERT`. Remove `testr_name =` etc.

Comment: For the transaction requirement, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165291/how-to-use-sqltransaction-in-c-sharp .

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but I think you should read this https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning up a bit your query or paste it on SSMS and declare your parameters and you will figure out what is wrong.

In your case your `INSERT` statement has some errors.

1. This is not valid syntax `VALUES (test_name = @combobox1)` instead you only pass the parameter `VALUES (@combobox1)`
2. There are more columns in the `INSERT` statement than values specified in the `VALUES` clause, you are not providing a value for apte_name. In the c# code you will need to add that parameter too.
3. You are missing the closing parenthesis for the `VALUES` clause

You should end up with something like this (not tested)

```
string selectQuery = 
@"BEGIN TRANSACTION 
            UPDATE tester SET 
                test_ad = @dateTimePicker1, 
                test_ud = @dt, 
                test_pd = @dt 
            WHERE test_name = @textBox1; 

            INSERT INTO records
            (
                testr_status, 
                testr_name,
                testr_ad,
                testr_ud,  
                testr_pd, 
                apte_name
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @testr_status, 
                @comboBox1,
                @dateTimePicker1,
                @dt, 
                @dt,
                @apte_name
            );

 COMMIT";
```

Comment: thank you. it is working! but when i checked it in ssms, it insert two records (duplicate records) . may i know why?

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is, that is one big, invalid SQL statement. Use the semi-colon to separate statements, like so:

```
"BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT ...;
UPDATE ...;
ETC ...;
COMMIT;"
```

That said, don't embed transaction statements in a query string. Do what Oliver suggests in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlTransaction

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlTransaction trans;
    trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
    string selectQuery = "your sql query";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
    int iResult = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (iResult > 0)
    {
        trans.Commit();
    }else{
        trans.Rollback();
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You might also wanna rollback in case of an exception being thrown.

Comment: Rollback is automatic. Upon exception, the using block will exit, closing the connection, implicitly rolling back any open transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Use a formatted string for your select query by using @ and the syntax in the value block in not accurate.

```
        string selectQuery = @"
BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE tester SET test_ad = @dateTimePicker1, test_ud = @dt, test_pd = @dt WHERE test_name = @textBox1;
        INSERT INTO records(testr_status, testr_name, testr_ad, testr_ud, testr_pd, apte_name) VALUES(@testr_status, @comboBox1, @dateTimePicker1, @dt, @dt); 
       COMMIT";
```

Comment: The `INSERT` statement is invalid.