# How to ensure rollback from without explicit ROLLBACK

Tags: c#, sql, transactionscope, sqlclient

If the ROLLBACK is out of scope because of the Catch block, assuming that is the cause, how am I supposed to resolve other than putting all the saves in a single method?

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DataAccess.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
string sql = "USE IncidentReports; BEGIN TRANSACTION;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();

try
{
    //if anyone of these saves fails, I want to rollback everything. No partial saves
    SaveIncident(connection);
    if (SelectedStatus.Key != _previousStatus) { SaveStatusChange(connection); }
    SaveEmployeeData(connection);
    SaveNotes(connection);
    SaveChecklist(connection);
    SaveExpenses(connection);

    _previousStatus = SelectedStatus.Key;

    HasBeenSaved = true;
    NewIncident = false;

    sql = "USE IncidentReports; COMMIT TRANSACTION;";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    sql = "USE IncidentReports; ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();

    var mbp2 = new MessageBoxParams()
    {
        Caption = StaticGlobals.MSGBOX_CAPTION,
        Image = MessageBoxImage.Exclamation,
        Button = MessageBoxButton.OK,
        Message = $"Incident was not saved, the following error occurred;{Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}"
    };
    ShowMessageBox(mbp2);
    return;
}
finally
{
    cmd?.Dispose();
    connection?.Close();
}
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/sql-transaction/ read the part about "Transaction with ADO.NET"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't manually do transactions with `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` unless it is all in the same batch (along with `SET XACT_ABORT ON`).

If you want a client-side transaction (ie you want the transaction to begin before any `SqlCommand`, and continue until all commands are done), you should just use `BeginTransaction` on the `SqlConnection` object.

Then each command is created using that `SqlTransaction` object. And you call `transaction.Commit();` at the end.

Furthermore:

- Put a `using` on the connection, command and transaction objects. Then you don't need the `finally`.
- Instead of `USE`, put the database you want to connect into the connection string.
- Do not block the calling thread with message boxes until you have closed the connection.
- Consider using `async` `await` in order to keep your UI responsive.

```cs
try
{
    using var connection = new SqlConnection(DataAccess.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    using var tran = connection.BeginTransaction();

    SaveIncident(connection, tran);

    if (SelectedStatus.Key != _previousStatus)
    {
        SaveStatusChange(connection, tran);
    }

    SaveEmployeeData(connection, tran);
    SaveNotes(connection, tran);
    SaveChecklist(connection, tran);
    SaveExpenses(connection, tran);

    _previousStatus = SelectedStatus.Key;

    HasBeenSaved = true;
    NewIncident = false;

    tran.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var mbp2 = new MessageBoxParams()
    {
        Caption = StaticGlobals.MSGBOX_CAPTION,
        Image = MessageBoxImage.Exclamation,
        Button = MessageBoxButton.OK,
        Message = $"Incident was not saved, the following error occurred;{Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}"
    };
    ShowMessageBox(mbp2);
    return;
}
```

Comment: The "ShowMessageBox()" is an event being listened for by the UI thread. I have incorporated your other suggestions. The "USE <database>" was just a remnant of working in SSMS where I was connected to multiple databases. It is in the connection string so it is redundant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a db transaction object

```
var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
```

and refer transaction to each SqlCommand's Transaction property

```
command.Transaction = transaction;
```

and after operations u can use

```
transaction.Commit();
or
transaction.Rollback();
```

or you can use a conditional rollback in your sql query

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

i dont sure but you can try to give an alias to your transaction like

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION A
COMMIT TRANSACTION A
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION A
```

if it not helps, you can inspect this.

[How to use SqlTransaction in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165291/how-to-use-sqltransaction-in-c-sharp)